Possible math research areas for an undergraduate physics student
I am a Bsc physics student who wants to be a mathematician.I would like to do an undergrad research project in math. I can't take any pure math courses apart from real analysis in my uni,But I have self-learned group theory,Abstract linear algebra,Real analysis and basic point set topology(I have solved most exercises in popular textbooks in these topics).
I have 2 questions:
1.In which topics of math can I realistically do a guided project with this level of knowledge? (I do not expect to come up with results, I just want a meaningful exposure to math research, which is also good for my profile).
2.How do I convince professors to take me in, when I don't have math credits to prove my knowledge and passion? Will online courses (that have offline exams) work? Please mention any other ways...

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Can you read previous projects in your university? If so, you might want to find some that primarily use the topics you know, then speak to their supervisors. They might know some appropriate projects for you. However, I don't have any advice on how to persuade them to help.

Some of my university profs are open to take in early undergrads. I will check on what you said. Thanks
